# How to restrict DIVs to be in same line

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have three DIVs:

```
<div style="float:left;" id="a"> a </div>
<div style="float:left;" id="b"> b </div>
<div style="float:left;" id="c"> c </div>
```

I want all DIVs in same line but in some browsers, last DIV come down because of size of content in DIVs.

How to restrict them to be in same line even their is more content in DIVs. In this case horizontal scrollbar will be used to see all content.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in a parent with [overflow-x](http://www.css3.com/css-overflow-x/).

Comment: It shows horizontal disabled scrollbar for main DIV even when there is no need. Is there anyway that it shows only when there is need.

Comment: The value of the property should be "auto", not "scroll". If that doesn't work, your browser isn't compliant. [Google knows all and tells all.](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+horizontal+overflow).

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your divs in a parent div and set '*white-space: nowrap*' on it. Also, set '*display:inline-block*' for you divs to get the desired effect.

Try something like this,

```
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;       
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;       
}

<div class="parent">
  <div  class="child" id="a"> a </div>
  <div  class="child" id="b"> b </div>
  <div  class="child" id="c"> c </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">a</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">b</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">c</div>
```

Comment: Will have the same problem, unless you play with css: overflow or [whitespace](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/white-space/).

Answer (score 0):

Please define height property.